# Special case for deferred rendering

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glsl, rendering

I wonder if the following is possible:

I want to render a scene in two passes. On the first pass detect the fragments that are actually visible and only those that are visible (i.e if I only have a single triangle that get's rasterized, any pixel not contained in the rasterization of the triangle is considered non visible).

I then want to use this information on a second pass to produce a more complex image.

The point here being, that not only do I want to ommit occluded fragments from the computation, I want to ommit anything that is not the result of rasterization.

The end goal is simple, abuse this kind of shader to render a  geometry containing opaque and transparent geometry. The opaque geometry is considered non-existentt in the first pass and discarded.

Generating a fragment map of only the first visible transparent fragments.

I then use this information on a second pass to generate ray-traced colors based on the transparency.

The goal being to reduce the number of fragments to only be the strict minimum necessary to actually trace the transparent geometry.

Comment: There are few ways to achieve it. 1. You can use depth prepass. It is the simplest way and it works very well. 2. You can use compute shader to actually filter geometry before rasterizing it. DICE have a talk about this approach. 3. You can store your fragments to the linked list during the first pass and shade them later. And it's hard to answer your question w/o additional information.

Comment: That sounds like a good answer however

Comment: Ok. I'll put it as is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways to achieve it.

1. You can use depth prepass. It is the simplest way and it works very well.
2. You can use compute shader to actually filter geometry before rasterizing it. DICE have a talk about this approach.
3. You can store your fragments to the linked list during the first pass and shade them later.

And it's hard to answer your question w/o additional information.